# How to justify the convergence of this integral to the surface integral?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\Omega \subset \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ and $B_{R_0}(0)\subset \Omega.$ Consider $\eta$ to be a cut-off function such that $\eta= 1$ for $[0, r]$ and $\eta=0$ outside $[r+h,\infty)$ with $0\leq \eta\leq 1$ being a smooth function. Then define a vector field $\zeta(x) = \eta(|x|) x.$

I want to understand why,
\begin{align*}
-\int_{B_{r+h}(0)} \eta'(|x|) |x| |\nabla u|^2 dx \to\int_{\partial B_r(0)} r  |\nabla u|^2 dx
\end{align*}
as $h\to 0.$

I see that $\eta'\leq 0$ so that the function smooth decreases from $1$ to $0$ between $(r, r+h)$, but the value of the derivative blows up as $h\to 0$ around the point $r$ so I can't see why the integral converges to the above expression. Any justification would be much appreciated.

This computation arises in the proof of the monotonicity formula due to Price (1983) for stationary harmonic maps. Price's theorem tells us that if $u\in H^1(\Omega, N)$ is a stationary harmonic map then it satisfies the following inequality,
\begin{align*}
r^{2-m}\int_{B_r(0)} |\nabla u|^2 dx \leq R^{2-m} \int_{B_R(0)}|\nabla u|^2 dx
\end{align*}
for all $0< r< R \leq R_0.$